# TCP. client connects even if server doesn't accept him

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I have TCP server-client application. It works but sometime something happens. Client connects to server but server says he doesn't accepted him.

Server side code:

```
while(!stopped){
            try {
                AcceptClient();
            } catch(SocketTimeoutException ex){
                continue;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("AppServer: Client cannot be accepted.\n"+ex.getMessage()+"\n");
                break;
            }
...

private void AcceptClient() throws IOException {
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(200);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Accepted connection from "+clientSocket.getInetAddress());
}
```

Client side code:

```
    try {
        socket = new Socket(IPAddress, serverPort);
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        sendSystemMessage("DISCONNECTED");
        sendSystemMessage(e1.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    sendSystemMessage("CONNECTED");
```

If client connects the message:

> Accepted connection from ... appears. But sometimes it doesn't appear
>   even if client sends message "CONNECTED"

Server is still runing the loop trying to get client and it is catching socketTimeoutException. Client is connected, sends message and waits for response.

Comment: You're leaking sockets. You're not catching `SocketTimeoutException` separately, which does *not* indicate a disconnection. Your read timeout is too short at the server. The server should not construct the object streams in the accept loop: they should be constructed in the `run()` method of the connection thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The communication on my net is too slow so it timeouts in getting inputstream. The solution has two parts. Flushing outputstream before getting inputstream. And set socket timout after streams are initialized.

serverside:

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
out.flush()
in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
clientSocket.setSoTimeout(200);
```

Comment: The `flush()` is unnecessary unless you have a `BufferedOutputStream;` 200ms is far too short for a read timeout, and the rest you were told several days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a missing 'flush' inside your client's 'sendSystemMessage()'.
Unfortunately the **constructor** of ObjectInputStream attempts to read a header from the underlying stream (which is not very intuitive IMHO). So if the client fails to flush the data - the server may remain stuck on the line "in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())"...

As a side note it's usually better for a server to launch a thread per incoming client, but that's just a side remark (plus it obviously depends on requirements).

Comment: sendSystemMessage is sending message inside of android app. But you are right server is stucking on line in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
But every message sent from client to server is flushed.

Comment: could you also please reverse the order of 'in' and 'out' between server and client, eg client calls "in=new ObjectInputStream.."  then "out=new ObjectOutputStream.."  while server uses a revers order (first "out=new ObjectOutputStream... then "in=new ObjectInputStream...")

Comment: It's in same order now. Out - in on both. Should I reverse it?

Comment: @SpeedEX505 No, you will get a deadlock. Leave it as is.

Comment: I repaired it with adding line (out.flush()) between them.